# SVN Hooks Error

Tags: svn

My Jira ticket is in Unresolved State and status is In-Progress.
When i try to commit code in svn it throws error:

Error: ERROR:  Commit rejected -- No project accepts this commit. Project [*]: Issue
Error:  [PW-84] must be in UNRESOLVED.
Error:  You are NOT allowed to commit fix to a JIRA issue which is NOT in
Error:  UNRESOLVED state!
Error: This error was generated by a custom hook script on the Subversion server.
Error: Please contact your server administrator for help with resolving this issue.

Please Help to resolve this issue. This issue was not facing earlier

Comment: That means that the repository administrator has installed a pre-commit hook script to actively reject your commit based on the status of the issue ticked you typed in the log message. Either follow the instructions or talk to your administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You should address this question to your colleagues, manager or admin. Your commit is being rejected based on the policies set in your team for commits. This is not a technical problem.